# Github Programs Installation

Tags: github

I know this is probably a super silly question, but how do I install on my pc open source programs that I find here on github.
By installing I mean directly from the source code, and not by going on some external website and downloading the file from there.
I know I'm a noob, just go easy on me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github page of the program will generally show README file, and it would contain instructions on how to install this program. Sometimes you can find the instructions in wiki pages for this project.

There is no one general way to install something from github, it really depends on the software you are looking at.

Quite often, especially if it is a big project and is written in low level language, the main installation step is entering commands

```
./configure
make
make install
```

in your terminal, but this is only one of the different installation procedures.